# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible at Array.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this error when fetching data from firebase and pushing the data into an array.
Here I define a temp array when I am pushing data inside firebase onValue into this temp array I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible at Array.push. Here is my code

```
function Room() {
const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
const temp = [];

const handleTextInputChange = (event) => {
    setTextInput(event.target.value);
};

const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log('here goes');
    if (textInput !== '') {
        const refer = ref(database, 'rooms/');
        push(refer, textInput).then(() => {
            setTextInput('');
            toast.success('Added Successfully!');
        });
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    const refer = ref(database, 'rooms/');
    onValue(refer, (snap) => {
        snap.forEach((child) => {
            console.log(child.val() + child.key);
            // I am getting error in this line
            temp.push({ id: child.key, firstName: child.val() });
        });
    });
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
                <SubCard title="Room List">
                    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                        <DataGrid
                            rows={temp}
                            columns={columns}
                            pageSize={5}
                            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
                            components={{
                                Toolbar: CustomToolbar
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </SubCard>
            </Grid>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I set this temp data to DataGrid

Comment: okay, i edited my question and add that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error you're getting is what you get when you try to push to a frozen array:

```js
const temp = Object.freeze([]);
temp.push(42);
```

You've shown that you're passing the array to `DataGrid` as `rows`. Apparently, `DataGrid` freezes the array, presumably because it needs to know that the contents of it don't change.

If you want to change those contents, you'll need to store `temp` in state and re-render after adding to it; see `***` comments (I've also renamed `temp` to `dataGridRows`):

```
function Room() {
    const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState('');
    // *** Store it in state
    const [dataGridRows, setDataGridRows] = useState([]);

    const handleTextInputChange = (event) => {
        setTextInput(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('here goes');
        if (textInput !== '') {
            const refer = ref(database, 'rooms/');
            push(refer, textInput).then(() => {
                setTextInput('');
                toast.success('Added Successfully!');
            });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const refer = ref(database, 'rooms/');
        onValue(refer, (snap) => {
            snap.forEach((child) => {
                console.log(child.val() + child.key);
                // *** Add to it in state; this will cause a re-render
                // so DataGrid picks up the change
                setDataGridRows(dataGridRows => [...dataGridRows, { id: child.key, firstName: child.val() }];
            });
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
                <SubCard title="Room List">
                    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
                        <DataGrid
                            rows={dataGridRows}
                            columns={columns}
                            pageSize={5}
                            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
                            components={{
                                Toolbar: CustomToolbar
                            }}
                        />
                    </div>
                </SubCard>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer TJ Crowder, it helped me to understand that the real problem is not the object that you are going to pass the value, but the original object, because it is passed by reference.

So, when you have the error

```
object is not extensible at array
```

The solution is to copy the values of the original object to the target, not just assign them with the equals (=) operator.

for example

```
targetObject.nodes.map( (newNode: any) => {

    //here I create a new object and enrich it with an array and a boolean
    let newFullNode = Object.assign({}, newNode, {nodes: []  , hasChildren:true}); 
    
    targetObject.nodes.push(newFullNode);
});
```

I update the targetObject later on, and when I was updating it,
only then I was getting the error, which was misleading me.

Answer (score 0):

The array is read only so what I do is just add a spread operator to it.

```
...
documents: [...d.distribution.documents],
...
```

Alternaively this worked as well

```
...
 documents: d.distribution.documents.concat([]),
...
```